# Grep exact word UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a file and I want to grep one specific word from that file. I am using MobaXterm. For example, I want to grep the word test-common and inside my file I have

```
 1. Version: 1.0.0    test-common Author Created Path   
 2. Version: 1.0.0    test-common-config   Author   Created Path    
 3. Version: 1.0.0    unit-test-common   Author   Created Path   
 4. Version: 1.0.0    unit-test-common-config   Author   Created Path
```

I tried:

- `grep test-common file`
- `grep "\\< test-common \\>" file` (don't return anything)
- `grep -w test-common file`
- `grep -w "test-common " file`
- `grep -r "\btest-common\b" file` (don't return anything)
- `grep -sw test-common file` (don't work)
- `grep -o test-common file` (don't work)
- `grep \\< bil-common \\>` file

Also `^bil-common` and `bil-common$` is not working either.

For the commands I had a result, the result was:

```
test-common
test-common-config
```

Which is not what I want. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The result is what you expected, no?

Comment: No i only want to get test-common not test-common and test-common-config

Comment: if there are no other characters in that line, you can do a whole line match - `grep -x 'test-common' file`

Comment: there is also other information in each line. but for the purpose of not posting any unnecessary information i wrote only what i wanted to find

Comment: @isovitis for text processing, every character can become important... would suggest to add complete sample input lines and show expected output for that.. as of now, seeing your samples and comments, I am not able to understand your use case

Comment: If your grep pattern is not a regular expression, you might want to try fgrep which looks for literal strings

Comment: so, does this command answer your question? `grep ' test-common ' file`

Comment: Above code `grep test-common file` work correctly. I think you linux distro have problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep -E '(^|\s+)test-common(?=\s|$)' file
```

This matches "test-common" that are followed only by a space or at the end of the line, and are preceded by one or more space, or at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @isovitis Your question is tagged with bash and linux, and the GNU grep used on Linux has supported the `-E` option for literally decades. Can you update the question to provide more details about your setup, e.g. mention if you are running the commands under BusyBox  or other non-standard environment?

Comment: @isovitis I'm not sure if it's supported there then. Do you have `egrep` available?

Comment: still not available.

Comment: @Maroun lookarounds not available with BRE/ERE... `grep -P` would work but OP mentions that is not available... imo, OP hasn't given proper sample input/output... I think OP wants to print entire line, in which case lookaround is not needed... and `[[:space:]]` can be used instead of `\s` if needed

Comment: this `grep -E '(^|\s+)test-common(?=\s|$)' file` is incorrect approach explicitely

Comment: @Maroun, cause it's simply NOT working. Read previous comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607611/grep-exact-word-unix/48607690?noredirect=1#comment84212551_48607690

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I still don't get it. And it **DOES WORK** given  the tags "unix", "bash", "shell" and "grep".

Comment: @Maroun, read `grep` documentation: there's no support for regex lookarounds in ERE mode `-E`

Answer (score 1):

1)I think that the easy way is to just do:
Add to string space before and after (in case you know that it is in the middle of a string)

```
       grep " string " file
```

2) if all of the answers doesn't work i would check that grep is not aliased by you:

```
   witch grep
```

or add

**\** sign before the grep making sure you use unix grep

```
      \grep " string " file
```